# C# - How to specify a property of a class for an update within a list

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following situation. I am updating data with Entity Framework Core. This works as follows. `product` is a dataset of table `Artikel`. So there is a `Artikel` class in my code.

```
...
foreach (var product in products)
{
    var oldStatus = product.Prodstat;
    product.Prodstat = newProductStatus.Nummer;
    Changelog changelog = new Changelog(product, "PRODSTAT", oldStatus.ToString(), newProductStatus.Nummer.ToString());
    string changeLogQuery = changelog.CreateQuery;
    var parameters = changelog.GetSqlParameterList();
    var result = _Context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(changeLogQuery, parameters);
}
...
```

I am currently only updating a single field as you can see (`product.Prodstat`). But now I need to update more fields.
I would like not to duplicate the whole code. I want to loop through the fields that need to be updated.
I imagine a kind of list that I can run through, like this:

```
List<FieldUpdate> fieldUpdateList = new List<FieldUpdate>()
{
    new FieldUpdate()
    {
        Column = "PRODSTAT",
        OldValue = oldValue,
        NewValue = newValue,
        Field = ???
    },
    new FieldUpdate()
    {
        Column = "_DATE",
        ...
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to specify the field, I would like to update.
In my initial example it is this part of code:

```
product.Prodstat = newProductStatus.Nummer;
```

If I want to update different fields, the field changes i.e. to

```
product._Date = DateTime.Now;
```

Is there a way to specify this `product.<field>` in my list?
I know, I'm able to query all properties of the class by

```
var fields = typeof(Artikel).GetProperties().ToList();
var field = fields.Where((field) => field.Name == "Prodstat").FirstOrDefault();
```

But this field I cannot use for an update, I think, because I need to update not the field itself, but the value of the field on the current product.

Comment: As a side note it looks like you are journaling/auditing the changes made to the product. I did it this way: https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET this might interest you.